# IntelliJ Idea - Git fetch from only one of multiple remotes

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, VCS > Git > Fetch works well if you have a single remote. However, for multiple remotes, how do you specify which remote to fetch from? It tries to fetch from all remotes.

Edit: Just to clarify, I want to fetch only not pull.

Edit: I'm not sure why the original question was not clear to some. I tried to clarify it.

Comment: Are you able to see branches for all those different remotes, when you see the list of all branches?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne If the branch is new, then no, I need to fetch first. And if it exists in one of the remotes, then I would see it, but I would still want to fetch to have the latest changes.

Comment: Actually what I wanted to know was whether you have added that remote as a remote of the project?? If yes, when you see all branches list from intellij, you'll be able to see some old list of branches of that remote. So you are seeing that old list right??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Yes, I see the branches for all remotes. And when I fetch, it fetches all remotes. I want to be able to fetch only from one remote.